# how to write subqueries in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a python code (pandas data frame )equivalent to the following code. I am able to join the tables but the subquery part I could not able to code.PLease help.

```
        declare    @test1 table (id int, market_date date , value float )
        declare    @test2 table (id int, market_date date , value float )


        insert into @test1 
        values (1,'2018-09-10',100),(1,'2018-09-11',101),(1,'2018-09-12',102)


        insert into @test2 
        values (1,'2018-09-11',100),(1,'2018-09-15',101),(1,'2018-09-14',102) 

        select * from @test1 

        select * from @test2


        select * 
        from @test2 a 
        where  a.market_date >=(select max(b.market_date) from @test1 b where a.id = b.id )
```

I am connecting with those tables throgh python and here is my sample what i have tried so far.

```
 df_test2 = pd.read_sql_query('select   * from test.dbo.test2', cnxn )
 df_test1 = pd.read_sql_query('select   * from test.dbo.test1', cnxn )

 d1=pd.merge(df_test2,df_test1,how='inner',on=['id'])
```

sample dataset and output

table test1

```
id  market_date value
1   2018-09-10  100
1   2018-09-11  101
1   2018-09-12  102
```

table test2

```
id  market_date value
1   2018-09-11  100
1   2018-09-15  101
1   2018-09-14  102
```

output

```
id  market_date value
1   2018-09-14  102
1   2018-09-15  101
```

Comment: Mention the dataset and your python code.

Comment: Please make this a question!!!

Comment: @yogkm Dataset would be the physical tables i am connecting the python code with DB. Here is the sample query. 


df_test2 = pd.read_sql_query('select   * from test.dbo.test2', cnxn )
df_test1 = pd.read_sql_query('select   * from test.dbo.test1', cnxn )

d1=pd.merge(df_test2,df_test1,how='inner',on=['id'])

Comment: @U9-Forward Please check the question now.

Comment: @priya Still wheres desired output and dataset

Comment: @U9-Forward Please check now.

Comment: @priya Okay good

Answer (score 1):

Assume,
df1

```
id  market_date value
1   2018-09-10  100
1   2018-09-11  101
1   2018-09-12  102
```

df2

```
id  market_date value
1   2018-09-11  100
1   2018-09-15  101
1   2018-09-14  102
```

In order to get the result you need you can run following code

```
d2[d2.market_date > max(d1.market_date)]
```

Comment: This is ok when there is an only single id in dataset what if there are more than 1 ids. I want to join dataset and add a market_date condition at once.

Comment: I really appreciate if you can help here.